# How do I set filters (if it is there) on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I want to answer the questions relevant to what I know about and willing to learn more about particular. When I select a question I see three categories, *newest*, *features*, and *frequent*. Can I create separate filters and create a new section called "your interested"?

Comment: update your profile that will take from there

Comment: What is the meaning of "you're interested"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I *think* they mean a list of the questions "you're interested" in.

Comment: Yes. Any way corrected to "your interested". @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're actually asking about what shows up when you click "Questions" in the top bar, not "a question", because a question does not have a tab for "featured" or "frequent".

If you want to filter what you see in the Questions list, you have several options, under Edit Profile & Settings > Site Settings > Preferences.

- You can add Favorite Tags, which will alter what questions are highlighted (and what shows up when you click the site logo).
- You can also take part in the New Question Filter (also know as "new-nav" here on Meta), which will let you create new tabs with whatever filters you want. One caveat is that this feature is kind of buggy, as you can see if you look at the questions in the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav)  tag here on Meta.

There are also other ways of getting filtered lists of questions:

- Search for the tags you're interested in. For instance, typing `[javascript][html]` into the search bar, you'll see all of the questions with the tags [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html). Or type `[javascript] or [html]` for questions with either tag.
- For individual tags, you can click on the tag in a question or from the [Tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and see questions with that tag.
- If you've added favorite tags, you can see only those questions with those tags by entering `intags:me is:question` into the search bar.

Comment: Another option is to write `[your-favourite-language]` in the search bar, and it will take you to the relevant tag page. For multiple tags it is `[tag1] or [tag2]`.

Comment: Thank you. I also wanted to know if there is filter based feature to fix it and modify it as my interests change. I mean to say new technologies and trends start everyday. Eg. Cloud, artificial intelligence, etc. I would love to keep a filter where I can keep adding and removing subjects of my interests as I go. That way I will get chance to see what kind of new questions/difficulties people are facing at the same time I also get the idea of how people thinking and approaching the learning those new subjects. More basic questions and answers I see more easily I parallellY learn.